# No apparent horizon in a Schwarzschild black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

Wikipedia claims ([Apparent horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_horizon)):

> it is possible to slice the Schwarzschild geometry in such a way that there is *no* apparent horizon, ever, despite the fact that there is certainly an event horizon.

Can anyone please clarify what exactly this slicing is? How should one slice the Schwarzschild spacetime in such a way that there is no apparent horizon ever?

Comment: I believe they mean that there is a coordinate transformation you can do that gets rid of the event horizon singularity. There is no transformation that can get rid of the central singularity though.

Comment: Did you check the reference given? https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1991PhRvD..44.3719W/abstract

Comment: sci-hub link: https://sci-hub.se/10.1103/PhysRevD.44.R3719 Their proof is constructive. But note that this doesn't evade the Penrose singularity theorem, since a trapped null surface does still exist for an appropriately chosen slicing.

Answer (score 1):

An apparent horizon is the boundary between radially outwards directed photons that fall in before they reach you and those which do reach you. If you are in the frame of an external stationary observer rays on the horizon never reach you, as you can see in Droste coordinates. But if you transform to the frame of an infalling observer, the rays at the horizon do reach you when you fall through it, which can be seen in Raindrop coordinates, where the g<sub>rr</sub> component of the metric tensor is not 0 anymore. For the transformation from Droste to Raindrop click [here](http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=422#coordinate.transformation), but there is still a horizon - just not an apparent one. So you can still see your feet when you fall into a black hole, but the light they emitted after they crossed the horizon will only reach your eyes after your head crossed the horizon too.